# problem with root s4 gt-i9515

Tags: root-access, samsung-galaxy-s-4

I have S4 I9515. Can I use a ROM or root S4 I9505 to my phone or not?

I don't find any root for my phone. I even tried to root my phone with root S4 I9505 but when I try to give super user access to my "root checker application" it give me "this device does not have proper root access". But if I delete "super user application" and then run "root checker", it show me that I got good root. Also I use another su app but it is not working with me so what to do?

Comment: Guess you're mixing things up here. To root a device, you don't need a special ROM. And your issue is: Never use two "SuperUser" apps simultaneously, that always gives trouble. There are ways to replace one by the other, maybe that would solve your issue. But to tell that, maybe you can [edit] your question and specify what exactly "not working" is supposed to mean?

Answer (score -1):

Try Frama root apk . 
It roots all high end devices.

How to install:

1. [Download Framaroot from XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=2784451&d=1402084843)
2. Run, choose Superuser or SuperSU
3. Select Boromir or another character
4. You will see `:-)`
5. Reboot device
6. Root- installed

Comment: Some more details could be helpful, for example where to find this and how to use it.

Comment: How to install:
1. Download Framaroot from our site
2. Run, choose Superuser or SuperSU
3. Select Boromir or another character
4. You will see :-)
5. Reboot device
6. Root- installed........................................... http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=2784451&d=1402084843

Comment: You should [edit] your answer to include this information as comments are temporary.

Comment: Did u mean that comments are automatically erased

Comment: Automatically, no. But they can be deleted at any time. Important information should not be left in the comments.